# Get the object from minio server without passing extra data into the URL

Tags: docker, devops, minio

I'm working on an app and I upload photos to the minio server. I want to access them from the frontend and I cannot simply write a location of the object in the url because it returns an XML response that says "Access denied.", so I have to pass the access key as a url query as well as it's expiration. Is there a way of enabling public access for every object in a bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mc policy set public <alias>/<mybucket>`

this would make the bucket and objects as public.

[Read more here](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/security/minio-identity-management/policy-based-access-control.html#minio-policy)

Comment: I'm not sure what alias stands for.

Comment: https://github.com/prakashsvmx/minio-js-web-browser-example. Try this

Comment: I actually have my own API so I wrote this functionality in go

Comment: Okay so I actually had to create a new alias. Now it works